# Nested JSON returned from ASMX called from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, asmx

I have the need to populate an HTML table client side. In an attempt to do this, I call an ASMX WebMethod from jquery. However, I have run into 2 issues for which I am asking for help.

First issue: The call is successful and clean json is generated in the ASMX WebMethod. I have included a stripped down(for readability) json sample below. However, when I try to parse the json in jquery it fails. It has somehow been wrapped in an XML wrapper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
...valid JSON data here...
</string>
```

I can manually strip the wrapper but I'm sure I must be doing something wrong for it to be there in the first place. Suggestions?

Second issue: After I have manually stripped the wrapper, I can parse the JSON but I cannot figure out how to extract "remark" and "statusTime" data nested in Report.ReportStatus and post it into an HTML table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    datatype: "json",
    url: 'WebService.asmx/GetINFO',
    contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: ajaxSuccess,
    error: ajaxFailed
});
});
function ajaxSuccess(data, status) {
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": data,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Report.ReportStatus.statusTime" },
        { "data": "Report.ReportStatus.remark" }
    ]
});
}
```

ASMX WebService

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetINFO()
{
    string url = "XXXX";
    string jsonStr;

    WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    try
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                jsonStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return jsonStr;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
    }
}
}
```

The WebMethod above sets jsonStr equal to the following JSON (stripped down for readability). I need to extract the "remark" and "statusTime" data nested in Report.ReportStatus and post it to an HTML table.

```
{
"ActivityDetails": {
    "referralTime": null,
    "Activity": [{
        "function": "delay",
        "activityStartTime": "2016-09-26T20:36:00Z"
    }, {
        "function": "work",
        "activityStartTime": "2016-09-26T20:39:00Z"
    }],
    "totalDuration": "0014:26"
},
"Report": {
    "Information": {
        "Priority": "UNDEFINED"
    },
    "ReportStatus": [{
        "remark": "Blah",
        "statusTime": "2016-10-05T01:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "remark": "Blah Blah",
        "statusTime": "2016-10-04T15:10:00Z"
    }, {
        "statusTime": "2016-10-03T17:24:00Z",
        "remark": "Blah Blah Blah"
    }, {
        "remark": "Blah Blah Blah Blah",
        "statusTime": "2016-10-03T17:22:00Z"
    }, {
        "statusTime": "2016-09-26T20:00:00Z",
        "remark": "Opened 09/26/16 16:00"
    }]
},
"Response": {
    "description": "Success",
    "code": "0"
}
}
```

Comment: Figured I could help ya out on this one... =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the webservice would return a valid JSON without the wrapper once the ContentType is set to `application/json`. Eg.:

```
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

For accessing the JSON data. Did you try JSON.Parse method. That should get let you create an object which could be indexed to get necessary values. In this case, it will be like,

```
data[0]Report[0].ReportStatus[0].statusTime
```

Comment: WRONG. Your code does not actually work. First of all, report is not an array. Second of all, data may not an array. Third of all, you forgot the dot on `Report`.